# How do I set the last updated time to dateSignedTabs in docusign, thru API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi

I have a date field in my document and I would like to set the last updated time of the document, or the time on which a particular event had occurred in the document. My document will have both signers and counter signers as well.

I am developing my application using Rails and I am using the Docusign REST GEM.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the envelope's history and audit events through the audit events API, then once you have your date you can simply set the value of your `dateTab` using the tab's `value` property.

NOTE: Make sure you use `dateTabs` and not `dateSignedTabs`.  Date signed tabs are populated by the platform, based on the date that recipient signs the document.